# how to change wordpress nickname settings default from username to name?

Tags: wordpress, user-registration

In wordpress in user edit page fields below exist :

- username* : which must be unique
- name
- nickname* : which is by default made from username
- List item
- display name

**I want to change that default to name**

in this [page](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/set-user-nickname-to-full-name-instead-of-username/) the solution below was suggested which did not work for me

adding thses code at the end of function.php in my theme :

```
add_action( 'user_registration_after_register_user_action', 'ur_insert_nickname', 1, 3 );
function ur_insert_nickname( $valid_form_data, $form_id, $user_id ) {
    $user_nickname = $valid_form_data['first_name']->value . ' ' . $valid_form_data['last_name']->value;
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'nickname', $user_nickname );
}
```

now does anyone has any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach Tested in(admin backend)

```
add_action('user_register','my_function');
function my_function($user_id){
  //do your stuff
  $first_name = get_user_meta($user_id, 'first_name', true);
  $last_name = get_user_meta($user_id, 'last_name', true);
  $user_nickname = $first_name.' '.$last_name;
  update_user_meta( $user_id, 'nickname', $user_nickname );
}
```

Comment: nah this only removed my nickname. my name was filled my last name was empty.

Comment: In the above code, I explain how to update nicknames while registration from the backend user page

username
firstname
lastname
nickname
Displayname

What you want to do Please explain and where from you registering user?

Comment: I understood the code. but it gave me empty nickname instead of firstname+lastname.
I am using a plugin called digits and it creates my registration form.
My website is in Persian called : kshopland.com
In my form I get name, mobile, password from my user.
username is created from my mobile phone number.
and apparently Nickname is made from username.
I am trying to change this

Comment: Ok, you are using a third-party plugin for user registration which paid plugin.

You have to find the registration hook in the Digits plugin and update the nickname by user_id